# Jquery: hiding empty table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tablerow

I am trying to write a script that detects if a tables `td`s are empty and if they are hide the parent `tr`

I've searched Stack Overflow and found other scripts but none seem to work for me.

So far I have:

```
$(".table tr").each(function() {                           

    var cell = $(this).find('td').html();       

    if (cell == null){
    console.log('empty');
    $(this).parent().addClass('nodisplay');
    }

    });
```

but just can't get it working. Any advice would be appreciated!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MeltingDog/S8CUa/1/

Comment: What is your criterion for "empty"? Is that no text, or no child nodes, or no elements and only whitespace, or nothing at all (e.g. `<td></td>`)?

Comment: @RobG nothing at all like your example

Comment: —so we just guess? My example does exactly what Musa's answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) only returns the content of the first matched element, so if your rows have more than one cell this wouldn't work. [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) might be a better fix, unless you have images or other empty tags in the cells.

```
$("table tr").each(function() {        
    var cell = $.trim($(this).find('td').text());
    if (cell.length == 0){
        console.log('empty');
        $(this).addClass('nodisplay');
    }                   
});
```

[*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/S8CUa/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
$("table tr td").each(function() {                               
    var cell = $(this);           
    if ($(cell).text().length == 0){
        console.log('empty');
        $(this).parent().addClass('nodisplay');
    }    
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yuqhk/3/)

Comment: kind of works - hides all trs excpet the first one regardless of if they have content

Comment: @MeltingDog Check the demo :)

Comment: Sorry, but on the fiddle you sent if you add a border you can still see the other tds

Answer (score 3):

you should try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(jQuery('table tr td:empty').parents('tr')).addClass('nodisplay');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to hide rows that have only whitespace content (but the cells might have other element child nodes). Using plain javascript:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var i = rows.length;
while (i--) {
  if ( !trim(getText(rows[i])) ) {
    rows[i].className += ' nodisplay';
  }
}
```

Helpers:

```
function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, '');
}

function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;
  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr').each(function(){

    var hide = true;

    $('td',this).each(function(){

        if ($.trim($(this).text()) != "")
            hide = false;

    });

    if(hide)
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        // OR $(this).closest('tr).addClass('nodisplay');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide table, if table have no rows using jquery

```
$('.tblClass').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.rows').length == 0){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```