# Hide empty html table rows

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem**

I have a table with one or more empty rows. How to hide empty rows from the table?

For example

1 - John | Alfredo

2 - Mark | Zuck

3 -      |

4 - Carl | Johnson

In this case, I'd like to delete the third row.

**Step Tried**

I found how to delete a specific row, what about deleting all the empty rows?

```js
deleteEmptyRows();

function deleteEmptyRows() {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")
  var rowToDelete = 2;
  myTable.deleteRow(rowToDelete)
 
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id ="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Alfredo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Zuck</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carl</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which do you actually want: to delete or to hide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: hiding empty table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283346/jquery-hiding-empty-table-rows)

Comment: How is the table getting built?  If it is being built by an object or json you could loop over the source data before the table is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can dynamically hide empty table rows with javascript.

```js
deleteEmptyRows();
function checkIfCellsAreEmpty(row) {
  var cells =  row.cells;
  var isCellEmpty = false;
  for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
    if(cells[j].innerHTML !== '') {
      return isCellEmpty;
    }
  }
  return !isCellEmpty;
}
function deleteEmptyRows() {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
  for(var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
    var isRowEmpty = checkIfCellsAreEmpty(myTable.rows[i]);
    if (isRowEmpty) {
     myTable.rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id ="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Alfredo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Zuck</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carl</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was answered in another thread. 
[Jquery: hiding empty table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283346/jquery-hiding-empty-table-rows)

Loops through all table tr rows, and checks td lengths. If the td length is empty will hide.

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {        
        let cell = $.trim($(this).find('td').text());
        if (cell.length == 0){
            console.log('Empty cell');
            $(this).addClass('nodisplay');
        }                   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Will hide --> <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, a simple method for row is empty (this allows us to check for other conditions easily later).

Loop over rows and call remove if empty.

```js
const rowIsEmpty = (tr) => Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td')).every(td => td.innerText === "");

deleteEmptyRows();

function deleteEmptyRows() {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
  
  myTable.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
    if(rowIsEmpty(tr)) tr.remove();
  });

 
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id ="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Alfredo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Zuck</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carl</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With native Javascript:

```
function removeRow(src) {
    var tableRows = document.getElementById(src).querySelectorAll('tr');
    tableRows.forEach(function(row){
        if((/^\s*$/).test(row.innerText)){
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }
    });
}

removeRow('myTable');
```

The only problem is when you have some other characters in the row, except the whitespaces. This regex checks for blank characters, but if u have a `dot` inside or any other non empty character, it will fail.