# Is it possible to display only one JSON object in a table based on a PHP $variable?

Tags: php, json, variables, show-hide, isset

I have a table that displays every object from an array using foreach(). I am wanting to have a search bar that enables the table to be filtered, displaying only one object and it's information. I have achieved this using this system for each key:

```
$searchname = $_SESSION["searchname"];
if($contents["attributes"]["Description"] == $searchname) {
    $description = $contents["attributes"]["Description"];
} 
else {
    $description = '';
}
```

**However, this then leaves every other row empty, but still being printed as a row due to else {''}.**

I've tried hiding every 'empty' row with some JavaScript queries from [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048952/hide-empty-html-table-rows)

```
deleteEmptyRows();
function checkIfCellsAreEmpty(row) {
  var cells =  row.cells;
  var isCellEmpty = false;
  for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
    if(cells[j].innerHTML !== '') {
      return isCellEmpty;
    }
  }
  return !isCellEmpty;
}
function deleteEmptyRows() {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
  for(var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
    var isRowEmpty = checkIfCellsAreEmpty(myTable.rows[i]);
    if (isRowEmpty) {
     myTable.rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work either, with every row still being displayed.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_search']) && !empty($_POST['submit_search'])) {
        $_SESSION["searchname"] = $_POST['submit_search'];
    }
$json = json_decode($buffer, true);
     $info = $json["features"];
     
     ?><div><table id="myTable"><tr><th>Beach Name</th><th>Patrolled by</th><th>Patrol freq</th><th>Updated</th></div><?php
     foreach ($info as $contents){
            $searchname = $_SESSION["searchname"];
            if($contents["attributes"]["Description"] == $searchname) {
                $description = $contents["attributes"]["Description"];
            } 
            else {
                $description = '';
            }
            if($contents["attributes"]["Description"] == $searchname) {
                $patrolledby = $contents["attributes"]["PatrolledBy"];
            } 
            else {
                $patrolledby = '';
            }
            if($contents["attributes"]["Description"] == $searchname) {
                $mil = $contents["attributes"]["last_edited_date"];
                $seconds = $mil / 1000;
                $date = date("d/m/Y", $seconds);
            } 
            else {
                $date = '';
            }
            if($contents["attributes"]["Description"] == $searchname) {
                $patrolfreq = $contents["attributes"]["PatrolFrequency"];
            } 
            else {
                $patrolfreq = '';
            }
           
            print("<table>");
            printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $description, $patrolledby, $patrolfreq, $date);
            print("</table>");
        }
    }
```

Now after searching for the beach 'Mooloolaba Beach', I'm left with something like:

| Beach Name | Patrolled by |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Mooloolaba Beach | Council |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Mooloolaba Beach | QLD Surf Life Saving |

*I've also tried isset() and !empty() in the if() query, but it seems as though isset() does not work with the '==' operator.*

**Is there anyway to hide these empty rows or just preventing them from printing in the first place?**

Comment: Please post your code, and especially the variants you describe trying.

Comment: @BadZen Thanks, edited to include all the relevant code being used.

Comment: @CoolColon use that upvote button instead of just saying Thanks.

Comment: It's not shown where your data is coming from, but surely the obvious solution is to omit the unwanted rows when the original JSON is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to just have one IF condition since it's the same in every case and then put all your variables assignations in it. Then you also insert the `printf` in this `IF` condition and both `print` for the table outside of the loop to avoid creating a table for every iteration.

```
 print("<table>");
 foreach ($info as $contents){
        $searchname = $_SESSION["searchname"];
        if($contents["attributes"]["Description"] == $searchname) {
            $description = $contents["attributes"]["Description"];
            $patrolledby = $contents["attributes"]["PatrolledBy"];
            $mil = $contents["attributes"]["last_edited_date"];
            $seconds = $mil / 1000;
            $date = date("d/m/Y", $seconds);
            $patrolfreq = $contents["attributes"]["PatrolFrequency"];
            printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $description, $patrolledby, $patrolfreq, $date);           
        } 
    }
 print("</table>");
```

Comment: Life saver! That fixed the problem quick smart, I see now the multiple 'if' statements caused unnecessary processing which I could just get rid of. Much appreciate your help!